# The move_base node doesn't provide an action server?

Tags: navigation, move-base, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have come across a weird one today. When launching the `move_base` node, there is no action server found at all. Initially I was launching in a launch file, but even doing `rosrun move_base move_base` provides no action server. The node launches fine, without any errors, and lists the topics that are unrelated to the server, such as `/move_base_simple/goal`, which works to move the robot. Using `rosrun actionlib axclient.py /move_base` also fails to connect. I haven't before used the actionlib interface for move_base.

Is there something fundamental i may be missing to cause this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262007/the-move_base-node-doesn%27t-provide-an-action-server?/) by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 885 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So in my launch file there was a problem with `map_server`, meaning a map wasn't available for AMCL, which caused `move_base` to hang at requesting the costmaps. The action server is started at the very end of `move_base` initialization, so this is all occurring before the start call. No errors resulted meaning it was hard to identify.

As for `rosrun move_base move_base`, it probably also hangs for the same reason. However, nothing is printed to console to tell you what's going on. Anyway, problem solved.

**EDIT: Aug 14 '17**

For me, the `move_base` action server didn't start because I wasn't providing it with a map, as it used a static map for its global costmap. If you aren't using `gmapping`, or don't plan on using AMCL, the best way to get going is to simply use a rolling window global costmap. This will be very similar to your local costmap, but perhaps use a larger resolution and larger size. You should then be able to use `move_base` without issue, as it will build the maps itself, rather than looking for an external one.

It only makes sense to use a static global costmap if you are usually going to be working in the same area, as opposed to using your robot in a different location every time. In this case, you should spend some time using `gmapping` to populate a map with obstacles, which can then be used as a static costmap. The `gmapping` node uses a laser to create a map in real-time, where each cell is either occupied, free, or unknown. The `gmapping` node can then share this map to `move_base`, which can inflate obstacles etc, and use it as the static global costmap. By default, `gmapping` publishes to /map, and `move_base` listens to /map. After using `gmapping` to map your area, use `rosrun map_server map_saver map:=/map` to save the map as a local YAML file and corresponding image.

The next time you come to navigate in the same area, turn off `gmapping` and use an instance of `map_server` to load the previously saved map. This way, the `move_base` node has access to the previously created map, and can efficiently plan a long distance path. If you want, you can also use AMCL to localize within the same map and provide the `odom -> map` transform which `gmapping` was providing, but this isn't related to any issue with the `move_base` server not loading.

So in summary, if your server isn't loading, check that there is something publishing to the /map topic if using a static costmap.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2017-08-10**:
Would you be willing to share your actual configuration files?  I am having a similar issue and trying to track down where I may have gone awry.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-08-13**:
I'll edit the answer with some more info.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-08-13**:
@benabruzzo I've added more info. Let me know which nodes (gmapping/amcl/neither) you're trying to implement and I'll upload a config for that.

**Comment by [mgrallos](https://answers.ros.org/users/91433/mgrallos/) on 2022-03-31**:
Hi I encountered the same problem, but I already run my gmapping node while running the actionclient move_base but it still says that action server not available.